# Error while setting Google Jib: Cannot find default setter in class com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.JibPluginConfiguration$PlatformParameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jib

I am using spring boot 3 with different micro-services. I am using micro-service architecture.

I want to use google Jib to build docker images of each micro-service with maven. I don't know what exactly is the issue with my configuration. I get an error when I try to use `maven package` command within a micro-service with activated profile:

`Cannot find default setter in class com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.JibPluginConfiguration$PlatformParameters`

I think there is something wrong with maven plugin, but I couldn't find out what exactly I did wrong.

Here is my main `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>learnservices</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>learnservices</name>
    <modules>
        <module>service1</module>
        <module>service2</module>
        <module>service3</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>3.1.2</spring.boot.maven.plugin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.5</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.boot.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>repackage</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <from>
                            <image>openjdk:17</image>
                            <platforms>
                                <architecture>amd64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platforms>
                            <platforms>
                                <architecture>arm64</architecture>
                                <os>linux</os>
                            </platforms>
                        </from>
                        <to>
                            <image>path/to:docker-hub</image>
                        </to>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>build</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Is there good reason why you are using an old version of the `jib-maven-plugin` plugin? https://central.sonatype.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/jib-maven-plugin/versions also the maven-compiler-plugin is not up-to-date (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/) also the spring-boot-version could be upgraded to 3.0.9 ... also spring-cloud.version could be upgraded 2022.0.4...

Comment: There we no specific reasons that I used these versions. I upgraded them but it didn't work neither. @khmarbaise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `<platforms>` look like this.

```xml
    <platforms>
      <platform>
        <architecture>amd64</architecture>
        <os>linux</os>
      </platform>
      <platform>
        <architecture>arm64</architecture>
        <os>linux</os>
      </platform>
    </platforms>
```